Unexpected output when inspecting binary QByteArray
I tried to realize how to put different data types to QByteArray to send them through Ethernet. I've seen a lot of topics about using QDataStream but i'm not sure that i'm using it correctly.
So here is my code:
    QByteArray data;
    QDataStream stream(&data, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    stream.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_9);

    quint16 val1 = 0x9876;
    quint32 val2 = 0x12345678;
    QString val3("12345");


so, when i try this:
    stream << val1;
    stream << val2;
    stream << val3.toUtf8();

in
    qDebug() << "data: " << data;

i expect
data:  "\x98\x76"
data:  "\x12\x34\x56\x78"
data:  "12345"

but get
data:  "\x98v"
data:  "\x12""4Vx"
data:  "\x00\x00\x00$12345"

what am i doing wrong?

Printable characters will be printed as their characters.

0x61 is lowercase 'a'. 'a' + 21 = 'v'.

If you absolutely must use qDebug here, print data.toHex() instead, which prints a hex representation of the byte array's contents.

@Botje no, i just use it to control my messages. toHex() is not what i've expected but now i see data:  "0000" with val1 and data:  "00000000" with val2 and it seems that smth is wrong. And btw why toUtf8() adds exstra symbols to my message?

You misunderstand QDataStream - it streams data into a binary format. The format is not documented anywhere so using it for anything else than de-serialize the data with QDataStream will fail. For pod types QDataStream simply writes the bytes in big endian, for all others it's using some internal representation(e.g. for QString/QByteArray four bytes as length identifier are added).
